# Give an efficient algorithm (both space & time) to find the 10 most frequent words in book

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash

Given a book with millions & millions of words.All the words cannot be fit in the memory at a time.
Give an efficient algorithm (both space & time) to find the 10 most frequent words.

My approach is to use a hash & store all the words. Generally hashes take values and multiply it by a prime number (makes it more likely to generate unique hashes) So you could do something like:

```
int hash=7;
for (int i=0; i < strlen; i++) {
    hash = hash*31+charAt(i);
}
```

If a word is already present,increment the corresponding count. Maintain a min heap of size 10.When a word is scanned,find its frequency.If it is greater than the minimum in the heap,delete the minimum & insert &update the heap.
At the last,we are left with the 10 most frequent words in the heap.
Whats the problem?
This approach works only when all the words can be accommodated in the memory at the same time.

Another approach is to use the external sorting as size of book is much as compared to the physical memory. After sorting, a linear search could do our job. But, what about the access time from the disk? Seek time & latency time can increment the access time.
So, this approach is also not efficient.

I can think of yet another approach: DISTRIBUTED HASHING (will work only when we have n machines). Distribute hashing among n machines. We may perform different strategies, say we have 26 machines, then we may hash all the words staring with alphabet 'a'('A') in machine 1,words starting with 'b'('B') and so on. We can then perform sorting or can use a TRIE data structure.

Is there any better way of finding the top ten most frequent words?

Comment: This is another (albeit rather esoteric) approch to sorting [Quantum Pagerank](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/108967-quantum-pagerank-faster-than-googles-classical-physics-version)

Comment: Even in theory you have to:


 1. Store all the word types so far (except maybe for the last M words if you already have a word that you counted more than M times more than other words)
 2. Go through all the book at least ones.

These are facts you have to deal with, any solution (that is complete meaning it Always returns the best result) you have that does not presume additional information (like that the book is sorted) has to have at least O(length-of-book) runtime complexity and 
O(number of words in book) space complexity

Comment: You seem to have the right thinking. Regarding solution 2 I want to add that usually you bring chunk into memory when you sort (instead of reading numbers 1 by 1 from disk) , and then dump the sorted chunks to disk. The again you read chunks from these sorted chunks into mem and merge them all into the final sorted list.